# Global styles for StencilJs custom web component not recognized in Angular app

Tags: javascript, css, angular, web-component, stencils

I've used Stencil to create a custom web component.

I've set a bunch of CSS variables in `/src/global/global.scss`:

E.g.:

```
:root {
  --font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  --font-size: 1.75rem;
  ... etc ...
}
```

My stencil.config.ts looks like this:

```
export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'my-component',
  globalStyle: 'src/global/global.scss',
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist',
      esmLoaderPath: '../loader',
    },
    {
      type: 'dist-custom-elements-bundle',
    }
  ],
};
```

If I publish the component to NPM, then install it into my Angular app, it works, ***except that it doesn't recognize any of the variables defined in the global CSS file.***

In my Angular project - the file is here, and does contain the variables:

`/node_modules/my-component/dist/my-component/my-component.css`

It's just that my Angular project doesn't seem to be aware of that file.

I've read elsewhere that I should include this line in the index.html file of my Angular project:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/my-component/my-component.css">
```

However, I've tried that, by when I run `ng serve`, the browser doesn't find:

`http://localhost:4200/dist/my-component/my-component.css`

I'm guessing that I'm missing some configuration setting that tells Angular to copy the CSS file from `/node_modules/my-component/dist/my-component/my-component.css` to `dist/my-component/my-component.css`, but I don't know how or where to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in angular.json:

```
       "styles": [
          "./node_modules/my-component/dist/my-component/my-component.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

Comment: thank you!! Just to confirm though - did you mean `angular.json`?

Comment: indeed, my fault!